# NetworkManager adding a connection but not setting the interface

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

I run the following to add a new connection to Network Manager:

```
nmcli con add con-name MIDVERCORP ifname wlan0 type wifi ssid "MIDVERCORP"
```

and when I look at my configured connections, this new connection has been added but the interface/device is not getting set to `wlan0`.

```
# nmcli con
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
eth0                1c71a54a-5ef1-4e32-ad02-8427f0168645  ethernet  eth0
eth1                57ce5d30-cde3-4b07-b83f-a5935f93cb6a  ethernet  eth1
MIDVERCORP          48e53a8a-ccbb-461e-bdca-74a837aa2c98  wifi      --
Wired connection 1  0eabbb3d-40d4-3031-a46e-14d87f9ac275  ethernet  --
Wired connection 2  fc12cba9-ee87-377d-ac4e-746a2f8fd6b3  ethernet  --
static-usb0         f93578c1-d309-4103-8554-fc1982ccda02  ethernet  --
```

```
# ip link show wlan0
5: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:ee:40:50:25:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What am I missing to get wlan0 interface set for this connection?

**EDIT**

To further show wifi is enabled:

```
# nm radio wifi on
# nm radio
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
# nm dev wifi rescan
Error: Scanning not allowed while unavailable or activating.
# ip link show wlan0
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:ee:40:50:25:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
# ip addr show wlan0
6: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:ee:40:50:25:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that wpa_supplicant was not running.

```
systemctl start wpa_supplicant
```

Then I could run `nmcli dev wifi rescan; nmcli dev wifi list` and see available APs.